# Movimentando personagem e mapa com canvas+js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, css3

Bom tenho uma duvida, gostaria de saber como eu poderia usar a imagem em tamanho normal, mas que eu possa navegar nela com as direcionais esquerda e direita, exemplo, tenho um canvas de tamanho 968 largura e 643 altura, e tenho uma imagem de 643 de altura e 2000 largura(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7gE6.jpg), como eu faria para movimentar um personagem(sprite) dentro dela e movimentando ele sobre o mapa? sem que ele ultrapasse o limite da imagem mãe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu precisa de um sistema de câmera ou viewport. Usa o `translate` do canvas, que já move todos os objetos desenhados de acordo e não precisamos ficar calculando posições relativas, e depois desenha tudo com coordenadas em relação ao mundo (a imagem):

```js
var iw = 2000; //Image width
var ih = 643; //Image height
var sw = 968; //Canvas width
var sh = 643; //Canvas height
var cw = 50; //Character width
var ch = 50; //Character height
var speed = 10; //Character speed

var img = new Image(iw, ih);
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/QnBufq4.jpg";
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var pos = {x: 0, y: ih - 140};
var camera = {x: 0, y: 0}

function draw() {
 //Faz a esquerda da câmera começar meia tela antes do personagem, mas só se tiver imagem suficiente pra isso
 camera.x = Math.min(iw - sw, Math.max(0,pos.x - sw/2));
 //Reseta as transformações do canvas
 ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
 //Limpa o canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 //Desloca o mundo inteiro, simulando uma câmera
 ctx.translate(-camera.x, -camera.y);
 //Desenha o fundo
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, sw, sh, 0, 0, iw, ih);
 //Desenha o personagem
 ctx.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, cw, ch);

 window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 var key = e.which || e.key || e.keyCode;
 switch(key) {
  case 37: pos.x-=speed; break;
  case 39: pos.x+=speed; break;
 }
 pos.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(iw - cw,pos.x));
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid black;" id="canvas" width="968" height="643">
</canvas>
```

E aqui, se quiser, um tutorial mais aprofundado: [Panning and scrolling background images using the canvas element](http://bdadam.com/blog/panning-and-scrolling-background-images-using-the-canvas-element.html)

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado meu amigo, salvo minha vida, não deu uma simples resposta, você resolveu tudo de uma vez ^^

Comment: poderia me enviar um zip? não estou conseguindo aplicar o mesmo no meu code :P

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite meu querido.
Não estou te dando uma solução em código, mas já lhe adianto que a solução não é movimentar o personagem e sim a imagem por trás utilizando paralax.

um exemplo do funcionamento da paralax
http://tableless.com.br/parallax-simples-com-jquery-e-css/

Caso veja solução nisso, lhe ajudo na procedência da situação.

Comment: Não é bem isso, bom vou dar um exemplo, digamos super mario, você vai andando e vai aparecendo novos obstáculos etc mas o width e height e igual na tela entende?

Comment: Você está usando autoAjuste? Eu uso auto ajuste com javascript para ele se adequar a tela independente da resolução. Não sei se estou pegando seu raciocínio corretamente. Mas tenho um jogo que fiz de curiosidade para caso queira consultar
http://atualgeek.com/jogo/

Comment: O jogo não precisa ja que ele está dentro de uma div canvas, o que eu preciso e colocar a imagem dentro da div( https://scontent-gru2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13442219_1794432477445121_7190000166730817106_n.jpg?oh=32f1f2dd77b6b5e6f085053bac902d20&oe=57C4CAB5 )

Comment: e colocar para movimentar o mapa ja que o canvas tem 940 de largura e a imagem tem que fica dentro dele teria 2000 entendeu, ai com as direcionais ao pressionar movimente, dando o efeito de movimento ao personagem

Comment: acho que entendi, mostraria apenas 940px do cenário inicialmente e de acordo com o movimento do personagem ele explorar até o px 2000? Seria algo do tipo? Se for realmente é paralax que vai lhe ajudar, pois o canvas e o personagem permanecem intactos e somente a imagem que vai movimentando de acordo com o pressionamento da tecla para o lado correspondente.

Comment: exato, n entendi mt bem como utilizaria o paralax, mas tem o porém no personagem, exatamente exploraria os 2000 pixel mas no finalzinho o personagem tbm poderia ir pra outra ponta do mapa, durante o percurso meio etc.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivfnUiCVnBU

Comment: Sim, mas eu sou meio leigo com jquery e javascript, teria como eu fazer isso sem criar muitas divis e arrastar com o mouse?